# Заполнить массив объектами js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Необходимо написать функцию, которая будет принимать параметры - год и срок, и возвращать массив из 12 объектов ДЛЯ каждого кода, также в каждом из 12 должно быть поле месяц от 1 до 12 соотвественно.

Пример:

```
год -2022
срок - 1
```

Результат:

```
[
  {
    year: 2022,
    month: 1,
    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
  {
    year: 2022,
    month: 2,
    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
  {
    year: 2022,
    month: 3,
    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
  {
    year: 2022,
    month: 4,
    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
  {
    year: 2022,
    month: 5,
    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
  {
    year: 2022,
    month: 6,
    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
  {
    year: 2022,
    month: 7,
    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
  {
    year: 2022,
    month: 8,
    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
  {
    year: 2022,
    month: 9,
    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
  {
    year: 2022,
    month: 10,
    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
  {
    year: 2022,
    month: 11,
    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
  {
    year: 2022,
    month: 12,
    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
  {
    year: 2023,
    month: 1,
    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
  {
    year: 2023,
    month: 2,
    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
  {
    year: 2023,
    month: 3,
    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
  {
    year: 2023,
    month: 4,
    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
  {
    year: 2023,
    month: 5,
    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
  {
    year: 2023,
    month: 6,
    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
  {
    year: 2023,
    month: 7,
    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
  {
    year: 2023,
    month: 8,
    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
  {
    year: 2023,
    month: 9,
    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
  {
    year: 2023,
    month: 10,
    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
  {
    year: 2023,
    month: 11,
    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
  {
    year: 2023,
    month: 12,

    plannedValue: "",
    achievedValue: "",
    plannedCost: "",
    achievedCost: "",
  },
];
```

Пробовал так, но что-то похоже не то:

```
for (let i = reportYear; i <= reportYear + validity; i++) {
        for (let k = 1; k <= 12; k++) {
          res.push({
            year: i,
            month: k,
            plannedValue: "",
            achievedValue: "",
            plannedCost: "",
            achievedCost: "",
          });
        }
```

Comment: А что собственно не так?

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в конце фигурную скобку.

```
for (let i = reportYear; i <= reportYear + validity; i++) {
        for (let k = 1; k <= 12; k++) {
          res.push({
            year: i,
            month: k,
            plannedValue: "",
            achievedValue: "",
            plannedCost: "",
            achievedCost: "",
          });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы указываете срок в номере, то эта функция вам подходит.

```js
function get(reportYear, number) {
  const arr = []
  for (let i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
    for (let k = 1; k <= 12; k++) {
      arr.push({
        year: reportYear + i,
        month: k,
        plannedValue: "",
        achievedValue: "",
        plannedCost: "",
        achievedCost: "",
      });
    }
  }
  return arr
}

console.log(get(2022, 3)) // 2022 + 3 = 2025
                          // from: 2022 // to: 2025
```

А если указать в годах, то это

```js
function get(reportYear, validity) {
  const arr = []
  for (let i = 0; i <= validity - reportYear; i++) {
    for (let k = 1; k <= 12; k++) {
      arr.push({
        year: reportYear + i,
        month: k,
        plannedValue: "",
        achievedValue: "",
        plannedCost: "",
        achievedCost: "",
      });
    }
  }
  return arr
}

console.log(get(2022, 2023))
```